C# Blazor .NET 8: Can't use @typeparam and @rendermode at the same time?
I would like to know, how it is possible to use a @typeparam while also using @rendermode InteractiveServer.
I get an error

Error CS0305
Using the generic type 'ManageList' requires 1 type arguments
Web   C:\src\ilink\ilink-api\Web\Web\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.Compiler.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Components_List_ManageList_razor.g.cs   124 Active

As soon as I remove the @rendermode, everything works fine, whether I'm calling the component or not.
This doesn't compile:
@typeparam T
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h3>Test</h3>

@code {
}

But this does:
@typeparam T

<h3>Test</h3>

@code {
}

I tried removing the @rendermode, and this fixes the issue. But I can't manage a way to use both at the same time.
Thanks

See Known Issue: Specifying a @rendermode fails when a component uses @typeparam, there's a workaround for it
